# multiple makefiles in one directory

Tags: makefile

I have a makefile in a directory of mine which builds scripts with certain environment variables set. What if I want to create another makefile in the same directory with different environment variables set? How should I name the two make files? Does `makefile.1` and `makefile.2` work? How do I call them?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You can give sensible names to the files like makefile.win and makefile.nix and use them:

```
make -f makefile.win
make -f makefile.nix
```

or have a Makefile that contains:

```
win:
  make -f makefile.win

nix:
  make -f makefile.nix
```

and use `make win` or `make nix`

Comment: In the latter case, what will be the default behavior of `make`?

Comment: By default it will use the one called Makefile. And if you don't specify a target, the default target is the one in the first recipe in the file (which can of course depend on later ones).

Answer (score 21):

You can name makefile whatever you want. I usually name it like `somename.mk`.  To use it later you need to tell make what makefile you want. Use `-f` option for this:

```
make -f somename.mk
```

Answer (score 12):

Actually you can have two set of environment variables in the same make file. for example

```
COMPILER = gcc
CCFLAGS1 = -g
CCFLAGS2 = -Wall

a: main.c
        ${COMPILER} ${CCFLAGS1} main.c
b: test.c
        ${COMPILER} ${CCFLAGS2} test.c
```

then you can just say `make a` or `make b`. Depending on what you want.

Also it is possible with -f flag to call which makefile you want to call.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this rather than using multiple makefiles for the same purpose. You can pass the environment or set a flag to the same makefile. For eg:

```
    ifeq ($(ENV),ENV1)
     ENV_VAR = THIS
    else
     ENV_VAR = THAT
    endif

    default : test

    .PHONY : test
    test:
            @echo $(ENV_VAR)
```

Then you can simply run the make command with arguments

```
    make ENV=ENV1
```

Answer (score 1):

I have two makefiles in the same directory. Many of the recipes have identical names and here are two solutions:

#### 1. Prefix in make

```
proja_hello:
           @echo "hello A"

projb_hello:
           @echo "hello N"
```

#### 2. Keep two separate files

1. Project A has `makefile`. Type `make hello`.
2. Project B has a separate make file called `projb.mk`. Type `bmake hello`.
3. This works since I've added `alias bmake ='make -f projb.mk` to my .bashrc. Note! This command can be called anywhere but only works where projb.mk exists.
   Note! You lose autocompletion of make with the alias and typing `make -f projb.mk hello` is not better than typing `make projb_hello`.