# Generate make file

Tags: go, makefile

I have a golang CLI program which generates a `makefile` to a specific project. While this works, there is an issue when the project already has a makefile. Of course I can check that in advance to avoid collusion, but how is it suggested to do it?

I'm not an expert in makefiles, but how can I create second makefile (maybe with the project name or something) that user can run via make (I guess with additional steps or info to the terminal)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/12057852/13860

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate it as `Makefile.project` and document to be run as `make -f Makefile.project`

Answer (score 3):

You can give your `Makefile` whatever filename. Then `make` must be executed with parameter `-f <your_filename>` or `--file=<your_filename>`. See [make manual on filenames](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Makefile-Names.html).

Answer (score 0):

Which version of make are you using? Some versions run special makefiles before others. For example, GNU make looks for the following files and runs the first one it finds: `GNUmakefile`, `Makefile`, `makefile`.

If you are using GNU make, then name your generated file `GNUmakefile` and add in the making any makefile already in the directory. That way, anyone running `make` in the directory will automatically run the generated makefike first.